# How to add the things in the case statement

Tags: mysql

My query is below

```
select date(created_at), 
  count(distinct  updated = '3'  then user_id end) as unique, 
  count(distinct  updated <> '3' then user_id end) as duplicate1,
  count(distinct  updated_by <> '4' then user_id end) as duplicate2

from user
where date(created_at) between current_date-2 and current_date
group by date(created_at)
```

I need one more column saying `TOTAL duplicates` which is the sum of both duplicate1 and duplicate2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new conditional count which includes both duplicate conditions:

```
SELECT
    DATE(created_at),
    COUNT(DISTINCT updated = '3' THEN user_id END) AS unique, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT updated <> '3' THEN user_id END) AS duplicate1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT updated_by <> '4' THEN user_id END) AS duplicate2
    COUNT(DISTINCT updated <> '3' OR updated_by <> '4'
              THEN user_id END) AS total_duplicates
FROM user
WHERE
    DATE(created_at) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 2 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY
    DATE(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to count the rows where `updated_by <> '3'` and `updated_by <> '4'` then you need the condition:

```
count(distinct case when updated_by <> '3' and updated_by <> '4' then user_id end)
```

or:

```
count(distinct case when updated_by not in ('3', '4') then user_id end)
```

so your code should be:

```
select date(created_at), 
  count(distinct case when updated_by = '3'  then user_id end) as unique, 
  count(distinct case when updated_by <> '3' then user_id end) as duplicate1,
  count(distinct case when updated_by <> '4' then user_id end) as duplicate2,
  count(distinct case when updated_by not in ('3', '4') then user_id end) as total_duplicates
from user
where date(created_at) between current_date-2 and current_date
group by date(created_at)
```

But if you want the distinct number of `user_id`s for `updated_by <> '3'` **or** `updated_by <> '4'` then this is equivalent to the distinct number of all the of `user_id`s, because all values of `updated_by` are different than `'3'` or different than `'4'`, so your query should be:

```
select date(created_at), 
  count(distinct case when updated_by = '3'  then user_id end) as unique, 
  count(distinct case when updated_by <> '3' then user_id end) as duplicate1,
  count(distinct case when updated_by <> '4' then user_id end) as duplicate2,
  count(distinct user_id) as total_duplicates
from user
where date(created_at) between current_date-2 and current_date
group by date(created_at)
```